# While using ajax with django form, getting error "Select a valid choice. That is not one of the available choices."

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

I am newbie in django. I am using simple ajax to dynamically update the choice field **semester** on the basis of **course** selection. But while submitting the form i am getting the error **Select a valid choice. *selected option* is not one of the available choices.** Code is as follow:

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from feedback_form.models import course,section_info

class loginForm(forms.Form):
     iquery1 = course.objects.values_list('course_name', flat = True)
     iquery1_choices = [('', '----------')] + [(id, id) for id in iquery1]
     sem_choices = [('', '----------')]

     course_name = forms.ChoiceField(iquery1_choices,required=True, widget=forms.Select())
     semester = forms.ChoiceField(sem_choices, required= True, widget=forms.Select())
```

views.py:

```
def get_batch(request, c_id):
    current_course = feedback_form.models.course.objects.get(course_name=c_id)
    batches = feedback_form.models.batch.objects.all().filter(course_id=current_course)
    no_of_sem = feedback_form.models.course.objects.values_list('number_of_sem', flat=True).filter(course_id = current_course)
    no_of_sem = int(no_of_sem[0])
    batch_dict = {}
    for batch in batches:
         batch_dict[batch.batch_id] = batch.batch_id
    sem = {}
         sem[no_of_sem] = no_of_sem
    data = [batch_dict, no_of_sem]
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
```

loginForm.html:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    {% csrf_token%}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#id_course_name').change(function() {
    request_url = 'login/get_batch/' + c_id + '/';
    $.ajax({
        url: request_url,
        success: function(data){
            data = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#id_semester').html('<option selected="' + "selected" + '">' + '' +'</option>');
            for(var i = 1; i<=data[1]; i++) //data[1] contains no of sem
                $('#id_semester').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i +'</option>');
        }, 
        errors: function(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    })

})
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `ChoiceField` requires the selected option to be in its choice set.

In the above code, the choices for `semester` are dynamically updating via jquery. However, these choices are not the part of `semester`'s choice set i.e. `sem_choices`. Hence the problem.

To solve this problem, include the selected value in `sem_choices` by using the `request.POST` method.

In views.py:

```
form = loginForm(request.POST)
sem = request.POST.get('semester')
form.fields['semester'].choices = [(sem, sem)]
```

Comment: This works after the first submit. But after a second submit (for example, when another errors are triggered, the problem appears again). Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to over-ride the valid_value() method of the ChoiceField. If you are not worried about the possible values the form could return, then it's as simple as this:

```
class AjaxChoiceField(forms.ChoiceField):
    def valid_value(self, value):
        return True
```

Or you could add more validation if needed.